# How to use onChange event to detect deleted rows with a Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-installable-triggers

[`onChange` event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) has the `"REMOVED_ROW"` type for a [`SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder)

However, nowhere in the documentation do I see a way to see **which row(s) was removed** from the event. Is there a way to get the row number(s) that were deleted with this event?

Comment: You can use [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange()). When a user removes a row it will automatically select the row that is below the deleted row.

Comment: Oh yeah, that could work. Call getActiveRange()  in onChange()? If they deleted multiple rows I might be able to use my index column to detect that multiple rows were deleted... I felt like there must have been a less hacky way to do this though.

Comment: I agree with you. It should be  built-in information but indeed, currently there is no other way but the hacky one Casper provided. @Casper you should add it as an answer

Comment: Any new ways to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange()). When a user removes a row it will automatically select the row that is below the deleted row.

Comment: This oddly bugs for me sometimes, I'm trying to mirror the deletes in another sheet, and when using this it sometimes delete 2 rows instead of 1. This doesn't happen if I put a msgbox up just before the delete though lol. It might have something to do with the way by events are firing (I have an onedit and an onchange, as far as I could tell its not firing twice but that would be the only explanation that made sense). Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why you'd have both an `onchange` and `onedit`. I'd suggest to perform all your actions in the `onchange` trigger. Consider making a new question for the issue you're facing now. It will allow to give us more details and it will get more attention from other users as well.

Comment: onChange doesn't trigger for individual cell/content edits. Only for overall sheet operations afaik

Comment: User may select another cells before trigger executes `getActiveRange()` method.

Comment: my onChange function does not even trigger if any row is deleted :(